# display that "ZIP/postal code" textfield in product view page

Tags: checkout, product-view

In magento checkout page, under "shipping address", we can see textfield "ZIP/POSTAL CODE"

I want to display that "ZIP/postal code" textfield in product view page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To point you in the right direction.

Take a look how it is provided in the checkout,
it is a block `checkout.cart.shipping` maybe you could add it to your productpage to have somekind of same functionality.

Comment: thanks a lot for reply. if possible can you give more explaiations about what and all have to do?